# Why $wp_query->posts[0]->ID and get_the_ID returns a different ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I am running those two outside the WordPress loop:

```
$wp_query->posts[0]->ID
get_the_ID
```

The first one returns of course the `ID` of the first post.
The second one returns the ID of either the first post or the last one. I would love to know why.

Basically I need to know information about the first post when I am in the header, which is why I was trying to use `get_the_ID`. I cannot enter the loop at this stage.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
global $post;
echo get_the_id($post->ID);
```

Comment: That too, it returns me the same ad as with get_the_ID. Different from the very first ID in my posts.